# Regex simple domain

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup, python-re

I'm searching for regex pattern which includes specific domain name.

For example:
`<any symbols>google<any symbols>`;

I'm start with

```
r'^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^.]+\.)? ....
```

How can I add domain name (google) in my regex?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? And what have you already tried? Stackoverflow aims to help those who try and not just ask. 
You may need to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: a domain name should include a TLD - do you want eg google.com?

Comment: I want to find solution without specific TLD. Just 'google' in regex with any TLD after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that I found:

```
(https?:\/\/(.+?\.)?google\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}(\/[A-Za-z0-9\-\._~:\/\?#\[\]@!$&'\(\)\*\+,;\=]*)?)
```

[regex test](https://regex101.com/r/2K1XD3/1)